# Consuming Kafka Messages in Spring

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

By following this [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-kafka), I was able to create a simple producer-consumer example. In my example there was only 1 topic and i was listening to that topic. For that reason, the code in `ReceiverConfig` makes sense. Specially the point around `GROUP_ID_CONFIG` i.e., i create topic `topic_name` and then it was configured in this configuration. Now my question is that, what if I have more than 1 topic. Let's say i have `topic_1`, `topic_2` and so on? Shall i create `ReceiverConfig` for each individual topic?

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class ReceiverConfig {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "topic_name");
        props.put(AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, you do not need to create multiple configuration for each topic.

Before going any further, I think there is good to specify that the `groupId` is the group which the Consumer process belongs to and `topic` to be consumed by the the Consumer process are two different things.

With the sentence below you will tell to the Consumer that its belong to the **topic_name** group, nothing more.

```
props.put(GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "topic_name");
```

If you want a Consumer to read data from multiple topics, there is a [**subscribe**](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#subscribe(java.util.Collection)) method which receives a Collections as a parameter, in that way you specify all the topics to read data without having to create a new configuration for each topic.

Please check this example out, you will see the method I mentioned

```
// Subscribe to the topic.
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(TOPIC));
```

Comment: Thanks but what if i want to receive each message in different receiver? so messages will be posted to `topic_1` which should be received by `topicOneReceiver` ... message posted to `topic_2` should be received by `topicTwoReceiver`. I actually have working copy of this change but i just want to make sure that i implemented it correctly.

Comment: What will be the difference between using `topicOneReceiver` and `topicTwoReceiver` from a logic point of view? I do not see the point to use 2 different Receivers.

Comment: `topicOneReceiver` has it's own bsuiness implementation. Let's say if it receives a number from the topic, it multiplies it with 2. `topicTwoReceiver` would have different implementation. E.g., based on incoming value it will subtract that value from a constant.

Comment: As of now, I have created individual receivers and individual topics. Which isn't scalable I.e., if I add more topic I have to add more classes. So was wondering what will be best eya

Comment: Remember that the `topic` to be consumed is part of the ConsumerRecord, so that you can have different logic depending on what `topic` your message record belongs to. Based on your use case, I would use the same receiver (which I would change the group name just for mental health) and I would start consuming data from different topics. After that, I would start scaling horizontally adding more Consumers to the group and consumer from multiple partitions. https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRecord.html#topic()